Decomposing multidimensional matrices into contraction of 2-dimentional matrices using the singular value decomposition.
My question is easy to state, but I will state it fist for 3-dimensions because I think it is more intuitive, then n-dimensions, and then the 2-dimensional case which I have solved. I feel like there must be a way to generalize my solution to the 2-dimentional case to higher dimensions, but I am not familiar with the higher-order singular value decomposition.
$\textbf{3}$ Dimensional Case
Given a $3$ dimensional matrix $c_{ijk}$ (where $i,j,k$ go from $1$  to $m_1,m_2,m_3$), find the minimum integer $t$ and $2$ dimentional matrices $d_{ij},e_{ij},$ and $f_{ij}$ that satisfy:
$$c_{ijk} = \sum_{l=1}^t d_{li}e_{lj}f_{lk}.$$
For example, for the special case of $i,j,k$ ranging from $1$ to $3$, and $c_{ijk} = 1$, the minimum integer $m$ is $1$ and $d_{ij}=e_{ij}=f_{ij} =1$ is a possible solution.
$\mathbf{n}$ Dimensional Case
Given an $n$ dimensional matrix $c_{i_1i_2i_3 \cdots i_n}$ (where $i_1,i_2,\cdots i_n$ go from $1$  to $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_n$), find the minimum integer $t$ such that there exists $2$ dimentional matrices $d^{(1)}_{ij},d^{(2)}_{ij},\cdots d^{(n)}_{ij}$ satisfying:
$$c_{i_1i_2i_3 \cdots i_n} = \sum_{l=1}^t d^{(1)}_{li_1}d^{(2)}_{li_2} \cdots d^{(n)}_{li_n}.$$
(Solved) 2 Dimensional Case
The two dimensional case: Given a $m_1\times m_2$ matrix $C$, find the minimum integer $t$ and a $t \times n_1$ matrix $D$ and a $t \times n_2$ matrix $E$ such that:
$$C = D^TE.$$
For the $2$ dimensional case, I have proven that the minimum $t$ is given by $\operatorname{Rank}(C)$ and the matrices $D$ and $E$ can be acquired as follows. First, compute the singular value decomposition of $C$ into $U,\Sigma,\text{ and }V$, so that
$$C = U \Sigma V^T,$$
where $U$ is a $n_1 \times n_1$ matrix, $\Sigma$ is a rectangular diagonal matrix with dimensions $n_1 \times n_2$ and with precisely $t=\operatorname{Rank}(C)$ non-zero elements, and $V$ is a $n_2 \times n_2$ matrix.  We define $U'$ to be the $n_1 \times t$ matrix formed of the first $t$ columns of $U$ and $V'$ to be the $n_2 \times t$ matrix formed of the first $t$ columns of $V$. Finally, let $\Sigma'$ be the $t \times t$ diagonal matrix formed of the non-zero diagonal elements of $\Sigma$. After we remove the entries that contribute zero, we have
$$C = U' \Sigma' V'^T.$$
Thus by choosing something like, say, $D^T = U'\Sigma '$ and $E = V'^T$, we are done.
Other Notes
I feel like there must be a way to use the higher-order singular value decomposition to do this, but reading the Wikipedia article is so far a bit of a brick wall for me. In principle, I will hope to implement this algorithm in code (Mathematica), so I'd also be curious if anyone knew of an in-built function there that can handle much of this. In the 2-dimensional case the function that computes $U',\Sigma',V'$ is simply SingularValueDecomposition[C, MatrixRank[C]].
This question arises when trying to find the minimal factorization of tensor product expressions like $a \otimes b \otimes c + a \otimes d \otimes c \to a\otimes (b+d) \otimes c$. For the $2$ dimensional case (with just one $\otimes$ symbol), the algorithm implemented above that reduces the question of factorization simply to one of linear algebra owes its credit to D.W. from this post: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/168863/algorithm-for-finding-the-minimum-factorization-of-a-tensor-product-expression.

The minimal number of summands in your decomposition is called the tensor rank of a hypermatrix $c$ (or the corresponding tensor). Computing tensor rank is NP-hard, and even approximating it up to a multiplicative constant is NP-hard. In practice, for small tensors you can try nonlinear least squares optimization ($\|c_{ijk} - \sum_{\ell = 1}^r d_{\ell i} \, e_{\ell j} \, h_{\ell k}\|^2 \to \min$) with some kind of search over $r$, but this cannot work for all tensors because there are $c$ such that $\inf \|c_{ijk} - \sum_{\ell = 1}^r d_{\ell i} \, e_{\ell j} \, h_{\ell k}\| = 0$, but there is no exact decomposition.
Higher-order SVD gives a different decomposition $c_{ijk} = \sum_{\ell,m,n} d_{\ell i} \, e_{mj} \, h_{nk} \, C_{\ell m n}$ where the core $C$ has some nice properties (slices in all directions are orthogonal). If this is enough for you, consider learning HOSVD.

This is insightful. You refer to the 'tensor rank of a hypermatrix' as being the minimum number $t$ that I seek. I am having difficulty finding discussion of this online. In particular, calling this: 'tensor rank' seems poor, as this is already defined, and is totally different (and certainly not NP-hard). Do you have a link to somewhere discussing this/giving a definition? So that I can try and implement such an algorithm in Mathematica.

Indeed, I did see the HOSVD decomposition $c_{ijk} = \sum_{\ell,m,n} d_{\ell i} , e_{mj} , h_{nk} , C_{\ell m n}$, but unless I can figure out a way to reduce the summation multiple summations to just one over $\ell$ then it probably isn't of much use. If however I could somehow guarantee that, say, $C_{lmn} = x \delta_{ml} \delta_{nl}$ for some constant $x$ then I'd be in business.

A good survey from the appled point of view is in T. Kolda, B.W. Bader "Tensor decompositions and applications", section 3 (SIAM Rev. 51(3):455--500, https://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf). The confusion with that the number of factors in a tensor is sometimes called rank is known, but it already appears when we discuss matrix rank of two-factor tensors, so it is better to call the number of factors "order" or "valence" (in some contexts "degree" and "arity" also work).

A more theoretical book is J.M.Landsberg "Tensors: geometry and applications". NP-hardness of tensor rank was proven by J.Håstad, "Tensor rank is NP-complete", J. Algorithms 11(4):644-654. Tensor rank plays an important role in the study of matrix multiplication complexity and is covered from this point of view in the book "Algebraic complexity theory" by Bürgisser, Clausen and Shokrollahi.

Your comments have been invaluable. In particular Kolda and Bader's paper "Tensor decompositions and applications" has been very useful. It is indeed dissapointing there is no nice algorithm to do what I want, and further, a guarantee I will not find such an algorithm.

For future readers. This is the wikipedia article on the tensor rank decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition

Perhaps there is a (albeit non-polynomial time) but deterministic algorithm for computing such a tensor rank: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947573/deterministic-algorithm-in-non-polynomial-time-for-computing-tensor-rank-decom
