Deterministic algorithm in (non polynomial time) for computing tensor rank decomposition.
Thanks to the insights from this question, I have determined that I would like to find an algorithm for computing the tensor rank decomposition (or even just finding the tensor rank) of a tensor. In my specific case the tensor is square of order 4 ($y \times y \times y \times y$), but in principle an arbitrarily algorithm would be nice.
As I understand it, computing the tensor rank in a nice way is an open problem. In particular, the problem is NP-Hard, and there are various aspects of the problem that make it difficult to attack (in particular, the fact that the answer will depend on whether the decomposition is performed over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$).
As far as I can tell the most commonly used algorithm for determining tensor rank decompositions is the CANDECOMP/PARAFAC (CP) method which is non-deterministic, i.e. it guesses various decompositions and then finds the one that is closest. This is not very useful to me.
Just because the problem is NP-Hard doesn't mean there is no good algorithm, only that there is no polynomila time algorithm. I am happy with slow algorithms, but am not aware of any deterministic algorithm for computing this, in any time complexity.
Questions
Are there any deterministic algorithms for computing tensor rank decomposition (or just rank)?
Even terribly cumbersome and impractical ones?
Additional information
In particular, the tensors I am interested in decomposing have integer entries, but are mostly zero (sparsity ~ 99%). Ideally I would like to decompose something like a $300\times 300 \times 300 \times 300$ tensor, but I am seeing it is unlikely I will be able to arrive at such a decomposition, even then it would be very useful for me to be able to decompose much smaller tensors.

I'm not aware of any deterministic algorithms except solving the system of polynomial equations coming from the definition of tensor rank, which is completely unfeasible for $300^4$. I wouldn't expect exact deterministic algorithms which are even remotely feasible (unless the rank of your tensors is very close to its size) because we have an explicit sparse (27 nonzero entries of 729) tensor of size 9x9x9 for which determining the exact value of rank would be a significant achievement in the field (this is the 3x3 matrix multiplication tensor).

You can test whether there is a decomposition of tensor rank $r$ for your tensor, by writing down a system of polynomial equations.  You will obtain $y^4$ equations in $4ry$ unknowns.  You could then apply any deterministic algorithm for solving systems of polynomial equations, e.g., Gröbner bases.  However I think the running time may be doubly exponential in $y$ and unlikely to be feasible for all but the smallest values of $y,r$.
